# How do i convert numbers to the words assigned in this program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a program where a list of numbers has to be converted to a list of words, by position in a list.  For instance:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1 ,5] #Input from user this is an example
words = ["apple", "pear", "lemon", "grape", "pineapple"]
```

The numbers in the "numbers" list are the indices of each item in the "words" list.
This output of this scenario should be:

```
apple pear apple lemon pear grape apple pineapple
```

Keep in mind that this is just an example; these lists will be taken from a text file.

Here is the part that I am stuck at:

```
for i in numbers: #i for the loop
    match = re.match(words.index[i], numbers)
    if match:
        numbers = words #I have no clue here
print(numbers)
```

This is just an extract from my program that needs some work done to it so the variables are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mapping` instead of unnecessary regex:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1 ,5] #Input from user this is an example
>>> words = ["apple", "pear", "lemon", "grape", "pineapple"]
>>> list(map(lambda x: words[x - 1], numbers))
['apple', 'pear', 'apple', 'lemon', 'pear', 'grape', 'apple', 'pineapple']
```

In human words, it means, `map` every number in the array `numbers` to its index at `words` lower by `- 1` to get a 0-based indexing.

You could gain the same result using

```
>>> [words[index - 1] for index in numbers]
['apple', 'pear', 'apple', 'lemon', 'pear', 'grape', 'apple', 'pineapple']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer for some reason it just comes up with a type error:

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Then your indexes array is probably strings (not as seen from the question). Try `words[int(x) - 1]` (`index` instead of `x` for the second example)

Comment: Thanks man! Your a real lifesaver. I`ve been at this one part for hours. Also I`m amazed that I didn`t realise that myself.

Comment: One last question. How can i display this back to the user in original form. (what i mean by this is how when i use the print() function around this statement it displays ["apple","pear","apple", etc] How can i display this like apple pear apple etc. without removing punctuation and special characters.)

Comment: With join: `' '.join(map(lambda x: words[int(x) - 1], numbers))`

Comment: I just done that and it now says that the index is out of range

Comment: Try `' '.join([words[index - 1] for index in numbers])` or your list includes indexes that are bigger than the length of the words list

Comment: It just says invalid syntax

Comment: Can you post the whole program? Upload to pastebin for example

Comment: Some of the variables are different but it`s the same thing

Comment: @HughSmith you set it to private visibility

Comment: Try now i have taken it off of private

Comment: `print(sentence.join([unique_words[int(index) - 1] for index in positions]))` you had several typos

Comment: What can i do to keep the spaces inbetween each word ("\s")

Comment: Last comment should have been `' '` instead of sentence.

Comment: Now it`s finally working as intended. I hope I didn`t take up too much of your time.

Comment: I just found a logic error in the program. When the user inputs a very long sentence the indexes don't work correctly as the positions are displayed as 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 4 2 3 1 3 2 4 17

Comment: What were the indexes ands words?

Comment: That was just an example I`m trying to figure out how to make this program deal with very long userinputs (changed to text files) with hundreds of words that occasionally occur multiple times. This is my program so far http://pastebin.com/EWt6etds

Comment: The positions have to match the indexes of the unique words so that the positions list has to be ascending with no gaps (meaning that the example above should be 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 4 2 3 1 3 2 4 5)

Comment: And the words in this case could be "a b a b a b c a b d b c a c b d e".

Comment: That example actually works however phrases like "the sailor went to sea sea sea to see what he could see see see" comes out with the positions being "1 2 3 4 5 5 5 4 9 10 11 12 9 9 9" which in turn messes up the decompression as the are more unique_words values as there are the highest number in the positions list, causing an index out of range error.

Comment: To be more specific the part that doesn't support breaking down a large amount of text is the following: 
    for position, item in enumerate(text):
        if text.count(item) < 2:
            number.append(max(number) + 1)
        else:
            number.append(text.index(item) + 1)                                             Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the list of numbers.  For now, use a **for** loop:

```
for index in numbers:
```

Inside that loop, you need to find the word matching that index:

```
    word = words[index-1]
```

... and then simply print the word.

**ADVANCED**

There are ways to put this into one line; I'm sure others will how you list comprehensions and **join** or **map** operations, such as the code below.  Pick your own comfort level for now.

```
print ' '.join([words[index-1] for index in numbers])
```

This is more "Pythonic" ... but learn at your own pace.

Comment: Probably `index-1`

Answer (score 2):

Very advanced, potentially much more powerful that ever necessary:

```
import numpy as np
words = np.array(["apple", "pear", "lemon", "grape", "pineapple"])
numbers = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1 ,5])
words[numbers - 1].tolist()
# ['apple', 'pear', 'apple', 'lemon', 'pear', 'grape', 'apple', 'pineapple']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  numbers = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1 ,5]  # Input from user. This is an example
  words = ["apple", "pear", "lemon", "grape", "pineapple"] 

  for i in range(len(numbers)):
      numbers[i] = words[numbers[i] - 1]

  print numbers
```